# How does google Drive fetch all containing files of folder while we upload folder?

Tags: google-drive-api

I noticed that while upload any folder on Google drive, Its automatically listed all containing files from an specific folder, however its all at client end and as per my knowledge no any client end language access client directory or system details then how Google Drive listed all containing files by giving only folder reference.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the exact implementation for Google Drive folder upload, but in HTML5, there is a **webkitdirectory** which support the operation.

See: http://earlysandwich.com/programming/how-to-upload-multiple-files-or-folders-with-html-and-php-168